# Utilizar un temporizador para un método de una clase Java

Tags: java, timestamp, timer, swagger

Estoy utilizando un método en mi clase Java. Lo que necesito es lo siguiente:

Si lo llama en la primera ejecución, que la aplicación (estoy con Swagger, por si tenéis dudas) no vuelva a llamarlo pasados 5 minutos de la primera ejecución. Se que hay un temporizador con timer o timestamp para esto pero no encuentro nada. ¿Me podéis ayudar?

Este seria el metodo a utilizar:

```
private String interruptor(){

    String resultado = Constantes.VACIA;
    GestorMaestra gestorMaestra = new GestorMaestra();

    try{
        //Aunque sea un Array solo devolvera una fila con las condiciones que se le envian
        BeanFilaDatos[] filaInterruptor = gestorMaestra.getTabla(Constantes.S10, Constantes.ISFANETO, Constantes.ES);
        for(BeanFilaDatos fila : filaInterruptor){
            resultado = fila.getCodigode().trim();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Querría algo como

> if tiempo > 5 minutos llamar al método

Cualquier duda o aclaración, decírmelo y lo reviso.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Deberías subir el código que tengas hasta ahora. Así te podrán ayudar mejor.

Comment: Añado metodo que quiero controlar cuando debo llamarlo

Comment: De primeras se me ocurre abrir un hilo nuevo con un timer en el propio método y supeditar la ejecución con un `if` hasta que ese timer haya alcanzado una marca, para luego cerrarlo al final... pero siempre hay que ser cuidadoso con los hilos. Veré si puedo trabajar en la idea luego.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar a realizar un temporizador de la siguiente manera:

```java
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

class Programa{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        /* ... Principio del codigo que tardara en ejecutarse ... */

            //Realizo una prueba de codigo que tarda 5 minutos en ejecutarse:
            try{
                //5 minutos de duracion (En milisegundos):
                Thread.sleep(300000);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        /* ... Fin del codigo que tardara en ejecutarse ... */

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;        
        float minutos = timeElapsed/(60*1000F);

        System.out.println("Tiempo de ejecucion en milisegundos: " + timeElapsed);
        System.out.println("Tiempo de ejecucion en minutos: " + minutos);

        //Si el programa tarda en ejecutarse 5 minutos o más:
        if(minutos>=5){
            //Ejecuta lo siguiente:
            System.out.println("El programa dura cinco minutos o más");
        }else{
            //Si tarda menos de 5 minutos, ejecuta lo siguiente:
            System.out.println("El programa dura menos de cinco minutos");
        }

    }
}
```

El resultado de ejecución por consola sería algo así:

```sh
Tiempo de ejecucion en milisegundos: 300000
Tiempo de ejecucion en minutos: 5.0
El programa dura cinco minutos o más
```